# Second domain (and name server), single IP

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain

I have a Windows Server 2008 with IIS 7 computer at home that has a static IP. A while back I've purchased a domain and have set the registrars DNS servers IP, so that the hostname resolves to my IP.

Can I now buy another domain from a different registrar, and simply add their DNS servers to my computer (under the IPv4 settings), and expect both of my domains to magically work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer, **yes**. Altough you want to server different pages per domain. In this case you have to configure your IIS to do [so](http://www.techstaty.com/how-to-use-iis-to-host-multiple-domains-with-1-ip-address/).